# Combining multiple .bmp files into a .mp4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine all these .bmp files into one movie.mp4.I am using **ffmpeg**.

[image: bmp files]

This command produces a movie of only 0.04 seconds:

```
$ ffmpeg -i f%05d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mp4
```

It should pick all the files up no? I don't know what I am doing wrong and can't find a solution.

This command I tried from [here](https://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/) says it can't find file with path 'f%05d.bmp' even though the above command can?

```
$ ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -start_number 1 -i f%05d.bmp -vframes 1759 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Comment: Answer depends on your OS.

Comment: *"It should pick all the files up, no?"* - As mentioned in one of the answers below, regardless of anything else, you likely need to make your frames sequential, without any gaps in the numbering (e.g. no `f69400` skipping to `f69440` as the next frame, just ex. `f00001`, `f00002`, `f00003`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think files should have consecutive numbers, otherwise they are treated separately (hence you get a 0.04 sec movie - just one frame). Few days ago I needed something similar (although not for ffmpeg but to import files into DaVinci Resolve) and I wrote a simple python script:

```
import os

filename="whatever{0:05d}.png"
destno = 1

for i in range(0, 10000):
   src = filename.format(i)
   if os.path.isfile(src):
      dst=filename.format(destno)
      destno+=1
      os.rename(src, dst)
      print "renamed {0:s} to {1:s}".format(src, dst)
```

Lousy, but worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the globbing to get all the .bmp files:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -start_number 1 -i %*.bmp -vframes 1759 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Comment: I get a " Could find no file with path '%*.bmp' and index in the range 0-4
%*.bmp: No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Then first `cd` to the directory where files are

Comment: Also you can't use `-f` with `-c:copy` (Codec copy)

Comment: `-f` and codec copy have no limitation with respect to each other.